# Columns names of top n values of each row in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
Data:
d = {'a': [1,5], 'b': [2,4], 'c': [3,3], 'd':[4,2], 'e': [5,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Desired Output:

```
d2 = {'a': [1,5], 'b': [2,4], 'c': [3,3], 'd':[4,2], 'e': [5,1], 'Top (First)': ['e','a'], 'Top (Second)': ['d','b'], 'Top (Third)': ['c','c']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

I would like to create 3 columns - `Top (First)`, `Top (Second)`, `Top (Third)` that return the column names of the top 3 highest values for that row. I tried an `np.where` and even though that works, it becomes exponentially longer with more columns so looking for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `nlargest` to find the 3 largest values, then get the index of the largest values (which are column names since we apply `nlargest` row-wise) and build DataFrame and `join` it back to `df`:

```
df2 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3).index.tolist(), axis=1).tolist(), 
                           columns=['Top (First)','Top (Second)','Top (Third)']))
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d  e Top (First) Top (Second) Top (Third)
0  1  2  3  4  5           e            d           c
1  5  4  3  2  1           a            b           c
```

Answer (score 0):

enke's answer is good enough solving the question within one library. Here's how you do with Numpy if you are feeling spicy lol.

```
import numpy as np

pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x:list(df.columns[np.array(x).argsort()[::-1][:3]]), axis=1).to_list(),  columns=['Top (First)', 'Top (Second)', 'Top (Third)'])], axis=1)

   a  b  c  d  e Top (First) Top (Second) Top (Third)
0  1  2  3  4  5           e            d           c
1  5  4  3  2  1           a            b           c
```

Comment: You could use `to_numpy()` and `tolist()` to construct arrays and lists. But this is very nice and should be faster than the one in my answer.